How to find duplicates in SQL where not all columns are duplicate (only some)?
Is it possible in SQL to create a query that returns all rows where some columns are duplicates, but not all?
Actionable example: consider this hypothetical SQL table with five rows in it:
| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| ABC      | DEF      | GHI      |
| ABC      | DEF      | JKL      |
| DEF      | GHI      | GHI      |
| DEF      | GHI      | JKL      |
| ABC      | GHI      | GHI      |

The question I'm asking is this: how can I write a query that will return/"select" all rows where both Column_A and Column_B are equal to that of at least one other row in the table?
To eliminate vagueness, here is a problem that if you can solve it you will resolve my issue:
What SQL query will return exactly these four rows and no other rows?
| ABC      | DEF      | GHI      |
| ABC      | DEF      | JKL      |
| DEF      | GHI      | GHI      |
| DEF      | GHI      | JKL      |

To do this the query must check if column A and B are duplicates of other rows, but ignore column C.
I thought that using a GROUP BY and HAVING would work, but those only work when all rows are duplicate, because it just returns each unique row, I need to return all rows where only some columns are duplicate.
Is this possible in SQL, if so how?

select * from t where (a, b) in (select a, b from t group by a, b having count(*) > 1) ?

@TheImpaler: works - IF your RDBMS does support this kind of syntax - not all RDBMS do ... (and the OP unfortunately didn't mention what concrete RDBMS he's using...)

Windows functions are probably the most efficient, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Column_A, Column_B) then check that for >1

You can do a select where you return all the columns and check with a subquery in your where the two columns who are equals.
SELECT 
    TABLE.Column_A, TABLE.Column_B, TABLE.Column_C
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    (TABLE.Column_A, TABLE.Column_B) IN 
         (SELECT TABLE.Column_A, TABLE.Column_B
          FROM TABLE
          GROUP BY TABLE.Column_A, TABLE.Column_B
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);


Word of advice: not all SQL-based RDBMS system will support this syntax .....
